# escaping @ in a string in quotes powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, escaping, powershell-3.0

I am trying run a curl command using powershell as follows:

`$command=".\curl.exe -k -X POST --data @login.txt -H ""Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8""  https://myserversfqdn:4443/ControlPoint/api/v1/login"`

`$res= Invoke-Expression $command`

It gives me an error saying the splatting operator @ cannot be used to refernce variables in an expression.. so I add the a backtick before @login.txt..

`$command=".\curl.exe -k -X POST --data '@login.txt -H ""Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8""  https://myserversfqdn:4443/ControlPoint/api/v1/login"`

`$res= Invoke-Expression $command`

Now it gives me an error saying the expression is missing a terminator ' (backtick)..
I am lost as to how to I pass the @ character in this command ?? Any  guidance is really appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks more like you are using the single quote charac ter `'` rather than the backtick:

> `

(Note that the backtick is usually on the same key as the ~ character.)

But you are half way to your answer, you could also wrap the whole argument in single quotes to pass it as an unparsed string:

```
$command=".\curl.exe -k -X POST --data '@login.txt' -H ""Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8"" https://myserversfqdn:4443/ControlPoint/api/v1/login"
```

Comment: Thanks zdan , I was using a back tick.. but it still didn't work, However putting @login.txt in single quotes as you have shown did the trick!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply:

```
.\curl.exe -k -X POST --data `@login.txt -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" https://myserversfqdn:4443/ControlPoint/api/v1/login
```